# Is Black/Cloud Ear Fungus toxic? Ought I shun it?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

My friend from Hong Kong read this [article](https://hk.news.appledaily.com/china/realtime/article/20180812/58552017) that reported two deaths from [*Auricularia polytricha*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_ear_fungus) poisoning. I can't read Chinese, and thus I'm assuming  his interpretation is correct. She then   warned me not to touch, let alone eat,  [*Auricularia polytricha*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_ear_fungus).

Is her fear warranted? Is she being level-headed and reasonable?

Every week, I make my own [Black Fungus with Ginger Strips & Vinegar Dressing](http://thesmartlocal.com/read/din-tai-fung-2016) based on Din Tai Fung's rendition:

[image]

Comment: I have eaten copious amounts of wood ear/rock ear fungi and I'm still alive, so I guess you have a living answer here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Cloud Ear Fungus is not poisonous, and is eaten by millions of people every day (mostly in China).  It is part of a whole family of "jelly fungus" which are almost all edible, and none of which are fatally toxic.
2. The article you linked cites two children who died of a bacterial infection due to black fungus which was soaked at room temperature for more than 2 days.  The article warns not to soak foods for too long.
3. You eat that black fungus dish *every week*?  Is this a medicinal regimen or something?

Comment: "You eat that black fungus dish every week? Is this a medicinal regimen or something?" Oh no. I just like it :D.